# Stripe Testing - Charge user right away even if subscription due date is next month

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a project that allows users to subscribe to our service monthly or yearly.

Now, I want to test our Stripe integration by attaching a working credit card, then changing that credit card into a "decline card" which I found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#declined-payments) (`4000000000000341`).

Now, I wanted to test that flow. I can see that the user's upcoming invoice is still next month, but obviously, I cannot wait for next month since I want to test it right away.

I was Googling and I see that they mentioned that I should put a trial date, I tried that by modifying the user's subscription in the Stripe dashboard, but seems not to work. Maybe I'm missing something or did something wrong? The current flow of our subscription basis is we don't have a trial period, so I am not sure if putting a trial date is applicable to us.

Any help/tips is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks).

You can simply advance the clock's time to one month later so that the upcoming invoice will be ready for you.

I believe the upcoming invoice won't be paid successfully as you are using a decline test card. You can read [this doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures) to learn more about invoice payment handling.